# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies

Currently, I am working on an android chat application. I want to add FCM in my app. But I am always getting this gradle error. From what I have read, the firebase auth, database and messaging dependency version should match. I have tried every version, still, the same error occurs.

[image: Snapshot of problem]

Comment: post the error as a text if possible?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617237/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-messaging11-0-4-in-android-stu

Comment: Please post your error log and build.gradle file

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/47833606/2919483 hope it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1
```

to

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2
```

and add:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1
```

Which is mandatory now. Don't also forget to add:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

At the end of your file and the following line of code:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
```

Into your `build.gradle` file (Project).

PS. If you are using Firebase-UI auth, add also  this line of code:

```
com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have forgotten to add `google() // Google's Maven repository` in `build.gradle`.

```
allprojects {
   // ...
   repositories {
       // ...
       google() // Google's Maven repository
   }
}
```

Here is the comment from firebase docs:

> // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
>
> // added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle

Here is the reference: [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase)

Comment: it is added allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: Alright. Can you please add your gradle files to question

Answer (score 0):

Add Maven to your project.gradle in repositories
LIKE THIS

```
repositories{ 
  google()
  jcenter()
   maven{
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Late post, but will help to someone...
Change your project level build.gradle file

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven{
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Make changes in app-level build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
}
```