# Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.+

Tags: android, firebase

In my working project, suddenly I am facing this issue. I did not update anything.

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@developmentDebug/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.+.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51551190/unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebug-compileclasspath-could-not-resolv)

Comment: you mistaken the version and please post gradle code.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using + in version number.

Try this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

The version `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.x.x` **doesn't exist** in the google maven repo.

You can check [the repo](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html).
Use one of the existing versions.

[image]